# cx_Oracle execute/executemany error when updating table

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I need conditionaly update Oracle table from my Python code. It's a simple piece of code, but I encountered *cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number* with following attempts

```
id_as_list = ['id-1', 'id-2'] # list of row IDs in the DB table
id_as_list_of_tuples = [('id-1'), ('id-2')] # the same as list of tuples
sql_update = "update my_table set processed = 1 where object_id = :1"

# then when I tried any of following commands, result was "illegal variable name/number" 
cursor.executemany(sql_update, id_as_list) # -> ends with error
cursor.executemany(sql_update, id_as_list_of_tuples)  # -> ends with error
for id in id_as_list:
    cursor.execute(sql_update, id) # -> ends with error
```

Correct solution was to use list of dictionaries and the key name in the SQL statement:

```
id_as_list_of_dicts = [{'id': 'id-1'}, {'id': 'id-2'}] 
sql_update = "update my_table set processed = 1 where object_id = :id"

cursor.executemany(sql_update, id_as_list_of_dicts)  # -> works
for id in id_as_list_of_dicts:
    cursor.execute(sql_update, id) # -> also works
```

I've found some helps and tutorials like [this](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) and they all used ":1, :2,..." syntax (but on the other hand I haven't found any example with update and cx_Oracle). Although my issue has been solved with help of dictionaries I wonder if it's common way of update or if I do something wrong in the ":1, :2,..." syntax.

Oracle 12c, Python 3.7, cx_Oracle 7.2.1

Comment: Your binding is fine.  You may additionally want to predefine memory as shown in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#predefining-memory-areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed bind with dictionaries but the overhead of creating the dictionaries can be undesirable. You need to make sure you create a list of sequences when using `executemany()`. So in your case, you want something like this instead:

```
id_as_list = [['id-1'], ['id-2']] # list of row IDs in the DB table
id_as_list_of_tuples = [('id-1',), ('id-2',)] # the same as list of tuples
```

In the first instance you had a list of strings. Strings are sequences in their own right so in that case cx_Oracle was expecting 4 bind variables (the number of characters in each string).

In the second instance you had the same data as the first instance -- as you were simply including parentheses around the strings, not creating tuples! You need the trailing comma as shown in my example to create tuples as you thought you were creating!